# Which layout constraint precedes with equal priority?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Given two constraints:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    aView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.topAnchor) //#1
    aView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: bView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10) //#2
    ])
```

Let's assume that the `cView.topAnchor` in constraint #1 is less (i.e. "further up north") than the `bView.bottomAnchor` in constraint #2.

Shouldn't this cause a conflict for auto-layout since it cannot satisfy both constraints because they have the same priority?

Strangely it doesn't - at least not in the log window, nor in the debug view hierarchy in Xcode.

My approach would be to set the priority of constraint #1 to `.defaultHigh` so auto-layout can break the constraint without conflict.

So is it even necessary to set the priority as there seems to be no conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EXPLANATION BASED ON DOCUMENTATION**

Two (or more) constraints with the same priority that cannot be simultaneously satisfied always cause a conflict. As per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ConflictingLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH19-SW1):

> When the system detects a unsatisfiable layout at runtime, it performs the following steps:
>
> 1. Auto Layout identifies the set of conflicting constraints.
> 2. It breaks one of the conflicting constraints and checks the layout. The system continues to break constraints until it finds a valid layout.
> 3. Auto Layout logs information about the conflict and the broken constraints to the console.

Documentation does not specify which constraint is broken - it's intentional, so that you would not rely on it, but rather **explicitly decide which one should be broken by lowering its priority**.

---

**EMPIRICAL EVALUATION**

You can simply test the behavior by setting two definitely conflicting constraints:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 81),
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
    ])
```

This will cause a conflict and will be reported in console:

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c0099550 molly.QuestionInboxLinkPreView:0x10791dd40.height == 81   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c008c300 molly.QuestionInboxLinkPreView:0x10791dd40.height == 60   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c0099550 molly.QuestionInboxLinkPreView:0x10791dd40.height == 81   (active)>
```

Weirdly enough, if you specify two conflicting constraints where both constraints have priority less then required ('priority<1000'), the conflict will be there, ambiguous behavior too, but you will NOT get a warning in the console. Be careful about that. You can test it using:

```
let constraint1 = view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 81)
constraint1.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
let constraint2 = view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60)
constraint2.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([constraint1, constraint2])
```

I guess the reason is that since the broken constraint is not `required`, the system does not care enough to report it. But it can cause some ugly situations - note it and be careful about it.

---

**YOUR EXAMPLE**

Now considering your example:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    aView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.topAnchor) //#1
    aView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: bView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10) //#2
])
```

Just these two constraints do not have to be conflicting. You are saying that `a.top = c.top` and `a.top >= b.bottom', which can be satisfied if` c.top >= b.bottom`. So unless there are other constraints with the same priority that conflict with` c.top >= b.bottom`, there is no reason for the autolayout to identify conflict.

Moreover, if the constraints are not `.required`, the conflict won't be reported even if there is one.

Comment: But it is that `c.top < b.bottom` (which i mean by "cView.topAnchor in constraint #1 is less than the bView.bottomAnchor in constraint #2"). So you are saying there has to be a conflict, but for some reason it is not displayed and coincidently the conflict is resolved by auto-layout in a way that I would want it? Maybe because in my code `b.bottom` is actually the `view.safeAreaGuide.bottomAnchor` so it creates a complexity where there is simply no log.

Comment: @Manuel I have to assume that either there is not really a conflict and you misinterpret your constraints (which can easily happen when the constraints are complicated), or that their priority is already not `.required` and in that case it won't be reported anyway (read updated answer)

Comment: Very unlikely that the constraints are misinterpreted because I i can confirm the layout by the visual representation. Maybe auto-layout handles constraints involving the `safeAreaLayoutGuide` in a special way. What is the default priority of a constraint?